# If $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \infty$ how does the $\lim_{n\to\infty} = a$ with $ a \in R$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $g$ be a real continuous function over $[0,\infty)$. Let $H$ be the set of all real numbers $h$ such that can be expressed as $\lim_{n\to\infty}  g(x_n) = h$ for some sequence $(x_n)  \subset [0, \infty)$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \infty.$ Prove that if $H$ contains two numbers $h_1$ and $h_2$, then it contains all the interval with extremes $h_1$ and $h_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose without loss of generality that $h_1 < h_2$ can be written as $g(x_n) \to h_1$ and $g(y_n) \to h_2$, $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} y_n = \infty$.

Let $h \in (h_1,h_2)$. Then for sufficiently large $n$, $g(x_n) < h < g(y_n)$ (Why?).

What does the Intermediate Value Theorem tell you about the interval with extreme points on $x_n$ and $y_n$?

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know in which book I can find these types of exercises?